# Transpose rows to columns in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a source file with the below contents:

```
0
ABC
1
181.12
2
05/07/16
4
Im4thData
5
hello
-1
0
XYZ
1
1333.21
2
02/02/16
3
Im3rdData
5
world
-1
...
```

The '-1' in above lists is the record separator which indicates the start of the next record. 0,1,2,3,4,5 etc are like column identifiers (or column names).

This is my code below.

```
$txt = Get-Content 'C:myfile.txt' | Out-String
$txt -split '(?m)^-1\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
    $arr = $_ -split '\r?\n'
    $indexes = 1..$($arr.Count - 1) | Where-Object { ($_ % 2) -ne 0 }
    $arr[$indexes] -join '|'
}
```

The above code creates output like below:

```
ABC|181.12|05/07/16|Im4thData|hello
XYZ|1333.21|02/02/16|Im3rdData|World
...
```

But I need output like below. When there are no columns in the source file, then their row data should have blank pipe line (`||`) like below in the output file. Please advise the change needed in the code.

```
ABC|181.12|05/07/16||Im4thData|hello    ← There is no 3rd column in the source file. so blank pipe line (||).
XYZ|1333.21|02/02/16|Im3rdData||World   ← There is no 4th column column in the source file. so blank pipe line (||).
...
```

Comment: Do you always have only one line of data? i.e. is every second line always content, or can it hold multiline values?

Comment: @arco444 Yes always have one line of data and no multiline values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the maximum number of columns beforehand you could do something like this:

```
$cols = 6
$txt = Get-Content 'C:myfile.txt' | Out-String
$txt -split '(?m)^-1\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
    # initialize array of required size
    $row = ,$null * $cols

    $arr = $_ -split '\r?\n'
    for ($n = 0; $n -lt $arr.Count; $n += 2) {
        $i = [int]$arr[$n]
        $row[$i] = $arr[$n+1]
    }

    $row -join '|'
}
```

Otherwise you could do something like this:

```
$txt = Get-Content 'C:myfile.txt' | Out-String
$txt -split '(?m)^-1\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
    # create empty array
    $row = @()

    $arr = $_ -split '\r?\n'
    $k = 0
    for ($n = 0; $n -lt $arr.Count; $n += 2) {
        $i = [int]$arr[$n]
        # if index from record ($i) is greater than current index ($k) append
        # required number of empty fields
        for ($j = $k; $j -lt $i-1; $j++) { $row += $null }
        $row += $arr[$n+1]
        $k = $i
    }

    $row -join '|'
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ansgar Yes, i too receives the same ArrayIndexoutofBound exception.

Comment: The exception was due to a copy/paste error. I forgot to change `$row[$i] = $arr[$n+1] ` to `$row += $arr[$n+1]`. As for spaces @MaheshMohan, please clarify whether or not your input file actually has trailing spaces. I was assuming that you added the 2 trailing spaces in each line for formatting purposes in your previous question.

Comment: @Ansgar Yes You are right. I added space for formatting purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Needs quite a bit of processing. There might be a more efficient way to do this, but the below does work.

```
$c = Get-Content ".\file.txt"
$rdata = @{}
$data = @()
$i = 0

# Parse the file into an array of key-value pairs
while ($i -lt $c.count) {
   if($c[$i].trim() -eq '-1') {
     $data += ,$rdata
     $rdata = @{}
     $i++
     continue
   }
   $field = $c[$i].trim()
   $value = $c[++$i].trim()
   $rdata[$field] = $value
   $i++
}

# Check if there are any missing values between 0 and the highest value and set to empty string if so
foreach ($row in $data) {
  $top = [int]$($row.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name -descending | select -First 1 -ExpandProperty Name)
  for($i = 0; $i -lt $top; $i++) {
    if ($row["$i"] -eq $null) {
      $row["$i"] = ""
    }
  }
}

# Sort each hash by field order and join with pipe
$data | ForEach-Object { ($_.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -property Name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value) -join '|' }
```

In the `while` loop, we are just iterating over each line of the file. The field number an value are separated by a value of one, so each iteration we take both values and add them to the hash.

If we encounter `-1` then we know we have a record separator, so add the hash to an array, reset it, bump the counter to the next record and `continue` to the next iteration.

Once we've collected everything we need to check if there are any missing field values, so we grab the highest number from each hash, loop over it from `0` and fill any missing values with an empty string.

Once that is done you can then iterate the array, sort each hash by field number and join the values.

Comment: Hi @arco444. That was nicely explained. Thanks! I tried the above code with the below set of file content, it didn't work. And the output become messy and some of the data's were missing too from the source file content in the output file.

Comment: This is written and tested based on the input you provided in the question. If the actual file you're using differs then I can't guarantee it will work. But you have the code now, so you should be able to modify it to suit ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for your code! I was editing your code for according to my change and in the mean time Ansgar responded. once again Many Thanks!!