# Can I convert a row of comma delimited values to a column

Tags: powershell, transpose

I have one row of temperature data in a text file that I would like to convert to a single column and save as a CSV file using a PowerShell script. The temperatures are separated by commas and look like this:

```
21,22,22,22,22,22,22,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,9,9,8,8,9,8,8,8,9,9,8,8,8,9,9,9,8,8,8,8,8,9,10,12,14,15,17,19,20,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,20,20,20,20,20,22,24,25,26,27,27,27,28,28,28,29,29,29,28,28,28,28,28,28,27,27,27,27,27,29,30,32,32,32,32,33,34,35,35,34,33,32,32,31,31,30,30,29,29,28,28,27,28,29,31,33,34,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,36,37,37,37,37,37,37,38,39,40,42,43,43,43,43,43,42,42,42,41,41,41,41,40,39,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,31,
```

I have tried several methods based on searches in this forum I thought this might work but it returns an error: [Transpose rows to columns in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46212269/transpose-rows-to-columns-in-powershell)

This is the modified code I tried that returns: Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

```
$txt = Get-Content 'C:myfile.txt' | Out-String
$txt -split '(?m)^,\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
    # create empty array
    $row = @()

    $arr = $_ -split '\r?\n'
    $k = 0
    for ($n = 0; $n -lt $arr.Count; $n += 2) {
        $i = [int]$arr[$n]
        # if index from record ($i) is greater than current index ($k) append
        # required number of empty fields
        for ($j = $k; $j -lt $i-1; $j++) { $row += $null }
        $row += $arr[$n+1]
        $k = $i
    }

    $row -join '|'
}
```

This seems like it should be simple to do with only one row of data. Are there any suggestions on how to convert this single row of numbers to one column?

Comment: What should be the column name? If I understand correctly, this should be as simple as split in comma and then add a header

Comment: Re the question you just deleted: make sure that the content of all input files is an _array_ of lines. If you use `Get-Content` with a _single-line_ file, you won't get an array, you'll just get that line as a string, and indexing into a string returns its characters. If you want a more detailed explanation, undelete your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# convert row to column data
$header = 'TEMPERATURE'
$values = $(Get-Content input.dat) -split ','
$header, $values | Out-File result.csv

#now test the result
Import-Csv result.csv
```

The header is the first line (or record) in the CSV file.  In this case it's a single word, because there is only one column.

The values are the items between commas in the input.  In this case, the -split on commas generates an array of strings. Note that, if comma is a separator, there will be no comma after the last temperature.  Your data doesn't look like that, but I have assumed that the real data does.

Then, we just write the header and the array out to a file.  But what happened to all the commas?  It turns out that, for a single column CSV file, there are no commas separating fields.  So the result is a simple CSV file.

Last, there is a test of the output using Import-csv to read the result and display it in table format.

This isn't necessarily the best way to code it, but it might help a beginner get used to powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding your intent correctly, based on your verbal description (not your own coding attempt):

```bash
# Create simplified sample input file
@'
21,22,23,
'@ > myfile.txt

# Read the line, split it into tokens by ",", filter out empty elements 
# with `-ne ''` (to ignore empty elements, such as would
# result from the trailing "," in your sample input),
# and write to an output CSV file with a column name prepended.
(Get-Content myfile.txt) -split ',' -ne '' |
  ForEach-Object -Begin { 'Temperatures' } -Process { $_ } |
  Set-Content out.csv
```

More concise alternative, using an expandable (interpolating) [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings):

```bash
# Note: .TrimEnd(',') removes any trailing "," from the input.
#       Your sample input suggests that this is necessary.
#       If there are no trailing "," chars., you can omit this call.
@"
Temperatures
$((Get-Content myfile.txt).TrimEnd(',') -split ',' -join [Environment]::NewLine)
"@ > out.csv
```

`out.csv` then contains:

```bash
Temperatures
21
22
23
```

Comment: I think your solution is more elegant than mine.  I was aiming for something that a newcomer to powershell could easily read and grasp.

Comment: Thanks, @WalterMitty. Given that the OP accepted your answer, you fulfilled your aim, not least because you also provided a detailed explanation.

Comment: @WalterMitty, the simplicity of your answer has it's own elegance. Two good answers, two thumbs up.